# What is replacement for <font size=“+/-X”> in CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, dom

for 1, 2, 3 we have:

`<font size="3">` is just as if you used `font-size: medium;`

`<font size="4">` is just as if you used `font-size: large;`

`<font size="5">` is just as if you used `font-size: x-large;`

`<font size="6">` is just as if you used `font-size: xx-large;`

`<font size="7">` is just as if you used `font-size: -webkit-xxx-large;`

what about `<font size="+1">` or `<font size="-1">` or `<font size="+2">` etc.?

Comment: what about '+1/2' or '-1/2'.

Comment: where did you get all that from, did you borrow a very old book from a library?

Comment: There are no direct conversions, nor do there need to be. The days of the `font` element are long past; it had a good run, but it's time to let go.

Comment: The time to let `<font>` go was some point towards the end of last century :)

Comment: The conversion algorithm is given in full in the [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#rules-for-parsing-a-legacy-font-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS doesn't have direct equivalents for relative values of the obsolete `size` attribute.

For font sizes relative to the font size of the parent element, use a relative unit such as `em`, `%` or `ex`.

Comment: hmmm size=-3 == font-size;70% ?